# delete records if 2 counts match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table with data

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| Trans   | Status | Step   |
+---------+--------+--------+
| ABCDE   | Comple | 1
+---------+--------+--------+
| ABCDE   | Error  | 2
+---------+--------+--------+
| FGHIJ   | Comple | 1
+---------+--------+--------+
| FGHIJ   | Comple | 2
+---------+--------+--------+
| KLMNO   | Comple | 1
+---------+--------+--------+
| KLMNO   | Comple | 2
+---------+--------+--------+
```

I only want to delete the records where the count of trans and status = 'comple' is the same as count of trans

I could probably do a cursor and loop but that is something I don't want to do.

Thinking along the lines of a having count but probably miles off.

Thanks

I just want to delete FGHIJ   and KLMNO   as I know all the steps completed.

I want to keep abcde as not all steps completed

Comment: I assume that your grouping value is Trans?

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete the `Trans` where there does not exist a row for that `trans` with `status`<>'comple'?

Comment: @TabAlleman I think the opposite. They want to delete those where all status values are "comple" and keep only those that have at least only other value.

Comment: @SeanLange yep, that's what I meant.   corrected my comment.

Comment: @tryingTocode could you please format the table properly?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale - it looks pretty clear to me. If there is some other formatting you want perhaps you should format it and show them as your definition of "properly" might be different.

Comment: @Seanlange it might be bcoz of mobile view! Leave it.

Comment: Now its in the proper table format thanks @Matbailie!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
--delete 
select *
from yourtable t
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t1.Trans=t2.Trans
    and status<>'Comple'
)
```

Use it as it is first to make sure this is what you want to remove, then comment out the SELECT and uncomment the delete

Comment: This definitely seems like the most sensible approach to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE  Trans IN ( SELECT trans
                  FROM   tbl
                  GROUP  BY Trans
                  HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Comple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) )
```

It deletes rows (by filtering on Trans), where the number of rows in a group of trans is equal to the number of rows in this group with the `Comple` status

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1768b/10

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE (Trans Varchar(10)   , Status  Varchar(10) , Step INT   )
INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT 'ABCDE', 'Comple' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDE', 'Error'  , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'FGHIJ', 'Comple' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'FGHIJ', 'Comple' , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KLMNO', 'Comple' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KLMNO', 'Comple' , 2

SELECT * FROM @Data

;WITH CTe
AS
(
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PArtition by Trans   , [Status] ORDER BY  Trans) AS TwocountsMatch
FROM @Data
)
DELETE FROM CTe WHERE TwocountsMatch=2 AND [Status]='Comple'


SELECT * FROM @Data
```

Demo Result :http://rextester.com/TYK92230

Comment: I don't think they want to delete row where the matching count is 2, I think they want to delete all "trans" where all of their "status" are "comple"...

Comment: I just want to delete FGHIJ   and KLMNO   as I know all the steps completed.

I want to keep abcde as not all steps completed

Comment: I just want to delete FGHIJ   and KLMNO   as I know all the steps completed.

I want to keep abcde as not all steps completed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to delete all of a `[Trans]` rows, if all of those rows `[status]` are `'Comple'`?

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE (Trans Varchar(10)   , Status  Varchar(10) , Step INT   )

INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT 'ABCDE', 'Comple' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDE', 'Error'  , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'FGHIJ', 'Comple' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'FGHIJ', 'Comple' , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KLMNO', 'Comple' , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'KLMNO', 'Comple' , 2

SELECT * FROM @Data;

WITH
  summarised
AS
(
  SELECT
    * ,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [trans]          )   AS count_trans,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [trans], [status])   AS count_trans_status
  FROM
    @Data
)
DELETE
  summarised
WHERE
  [status] = 'Comple'
  AND count_trans = count_trans_status
;

SELECT * FROM @Data
```